# The longest path between two points

Tags: matlab

The problem is that i want to go from the top right to the down left with a maximum summation of digits,and i have to do that with just 12 moves,actually it's a chem. eng. problem but the brief way of solving was the points i mentioned,I know these types of problems have some theories in graph and some algorithms , but since I'm a chemical engineering student i'm not so much familiar with the graphs and related algorithms.
I tried so hard to come up with an idea but i actually found none,i appreciate your ideas.

- note : we are allowed to do horizontal and vertical moves only

[image]

I used the answer and i got to this : (going from down left to right top,so moves are from down to top and left to right only,going from node 43 to node 7):

```
clc
clear

A = zeros(49) ;

A(8,1) = -3.02 ;

A(1,2) = -3.1 ;
A(9,2) = -2.04 ;

A(2,3) = -2.07 ;
A(10,3) = -2.09 ;

A(3,4) = -2.01 ;
A(11,4) = -2.04 ;

A(4,5) = -3.1 ;
A(12,5) = -3.03 ;

A(5,6) = -2.06 ;
A(13,6) = -2.05 ;

A(6,7) = -3.04 ;
A(14,7) = -2.05 ;

A(15,8) = -2.04 ;

A(8,9) = -3.04 ;
A(16,9) = -2.05 ;

A(9,10) = -2.02 ;
A(17,10) = -2.01 ;

A(10,11) = -3.1 ;
A(18,11) = -2.1 ;

A(11,12) = -2.09 ;
A(19,12) = -3.1 ;

A(12,13) = -2.08 ;
A(20,13) = -2.04 ;

A(13,14) = -2.03 ;
A(21,14) = -2.06 ;

A(22,15) = -3.05 ;

A(15,16) = -2.02 ;
A(23,16) = -2.09 ;

A(16,17) = -3.05 ;
A(24,17) = -2.07 ;

A(17,18) = -3.01 ;
A(25,18) = -2.08 ;

A(18,19) = -2.09 ;
A(26,19) = -3.03 ;

A(19,20) = -2.09 ;
A(27,20) = -2.02 ;

A(20,21) = -2.04 ;
A(28,21) = -3.05 ;

A(29,22) = -3.05 ;

A(22,23) = -2.07 ;
A(30,23) = -3.09 ;

A(23,24) = -3.05 ;
A(31,24) = -3.08 ;

A(24,25) = -2.01 ;
A(32,25) = -3.05 ;

A(25,26) = -2.01 ;
A(33,26) = -3.03 ;

A(26,27) = -3.04 ;
A(34,27) = -3.1 ;

A(27,28) = -3.05 ;
A(35,28) = -2.06 ;

A(36,29) = -2.03 ;

A(29,30) = -2.05 ;
A(37,30) = -3.05 ;

A(30,31) = -2.1 ;
A(38,31) = -3.06 ;

A(31,32) = -2.09 ;
A(39,32) = -2.09 ;

A(32,33) = -2.05 ;
A(40,33) = -2.07 ;

A(33,34) = -3.08 ;
A(41,34) = -3.02 ;

A(34,35) = -3.07 ;
A(42,35) = -3.04 ;

A(43,36) = -2.08 ;

A(36,37) = -2.05 ;
A(44,37) = -2.07 ;

A(37,38) = -2.08 ;
A(45,38) = -3.1 ;

A(38,39) = -3.03 ;
A(46,39) = -2.02 ;

A(39,40) = -2.09 ;
A(47,40) = -3.05 ;

A(40,41) = -3.09 ;
A(48,41) = -2.1 ;

A(41,42) = -3.1 ;
A(49,42) = -2.07 ;

A(43,44) = -2.08 ;

A(44,45) = -3.06 ;

A(45,46) = -2.01 ;

A(46,47) = -2.1 ;

A(47,48) = -2.02 ;

A(48,49) = -2.06 ;

G = digraph(A) ;

[path,d] = shortestpath(G,43,7) ;
```

But i get the wrong path length, matlab answer is 32.78 and the correct one must be 25.73 .
the path i find is :

43    44    45    38    39    40    41    34    27    28    21    14     7

the answer path is :

43 36 29 30 31 24 25 18 19 20 13 14 7

Comment: Possibly take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm, you would have to implement it to look for the least efficient path instead of the most efficient but it might work.

Comment: Agree with @user3716193. First create a topology then you can use The Djikstra's algo. Transform your weight with f(x) = 1/x and then compute the "shortest path"

Comment: I recommend you read [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-6-min-cost-path/), which is very similar, and adapt to your scenario.

Comment: Please post the `path` from your result as well as the distance.

Comment: The expected path that gives 27.7 would also be helpful.

Comment: The path given by MATLAB adds up to 32.78. The answer path adds up to 25.73 (not 27.7) according to my calculations. I haven't calculated all of the paths, but out of the two you give, MATLAB's answer is the longer path. Please add up the sum of the edge weights for each of these paths and let me know if you get something different.

Comment: @beaker yep you're right,so what should i do now ?

Comment: Well, if you've found a valid longer path, then the path given as an answer can't be the longest path, right?

Comment: Yep...actually it's a contest question,and it just made me uncertain about my answer,but everything seems correct..

Comment: I do hope you're not cheating on a contest. :)

Comment: @beaker of course not,we have no internet while the contest is going on,I'm working on previous years problems in my free time.

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili That's kinda what I thought. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the limitations on the available moves, you can model your problem as a directed acyclic graph. As noted in the Wikipedia article on the [Longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths) you can solve this by transforming all of the edge weights `w` to `-w` and applying [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) on the resulting graph.

The fact that your graph is acyclic is critical here, because it means that there will be no negative-weight cycles that would cause Dijkstra's to fail.

---

In 2015b, MATLAB introduced new graph functions, including one called `shortestpath`. This is what we'll be using.

**Graph representation**

First you need to construct your graph. There are a couple of ways you can represent a graph and which one you use in this case is simply a matter of which one makes more sense to you. We're going to pass the information to MATLAB's [digraph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) anyway, so as long as we give it acceptable input it'll work.

For either way, you first need to number your nodes (the grid intersections in your picture). How you number them is not important as long as you're consistent. I'll number the nodes 1-49: `1-7` on the top row, `8-14` on the second and so on until `43-49` for the bottom row. Here's a diagram of a few nodes in the top right corner of your grid that I'll use for demonstration purposes. (Remember we're changing all of the edge weights to their negative in order to find the longest path.)

```
              (-2.06)      (-3.04)
<--------  5 <--------  6 <--------  7
           |            |            |
           |(-3.03)     |(-2.05)     |(-2.05)
           |            |            | 
           v  (-2.08)   v  (-2.03)   v
<-------- 12 <-------- 13 <-------- 14
           |            |            |
           |(-3.10)     |(-2.04)     |(-2.06)
           |            |            | 
           v  (-2.09)   v  (-2.04)   v
<-------- 19 <-------- 20 <-------- 21
           |            |            |
           |            |            |
           |            |            |
           v            v            v
```

**Adjacency matrix**

One way to represent this is using an adjacency matrix. For `n` nodes, the adjacency matrix `A` is `n x n`. In our case, we'll have a `49 x 49` matrix. Each element in the matrix `A(i, j)` is `0` if there is no edge from node `i` to node `j`, or it is the weight of the edge. So the element `A(7, 6)` would contain `-3.04` because that's the weight of the edge from node `7` to node `6`. So, you just create the adjacency matrix

```
A = zeros(49, 49);
```

and start filling in the edge weights in the correct place.

```
A(7, 6) = -3.04;
A(14, 13) = -2.03;
A(13, 12) = -2.08;
and so on...
```

**Edge list**

Another way to represent the graph is using an edge list. Using this method, instead of a single `n x n` matrix you're going to use three vectors of length `m`, where `m` is the number of edges in your graph. The first vector `s` is the start (source) of each edge. The second vector `t` is the end (sink) of each edge. The last vector contains the weights for the corresponding edges. So, using the three edges from the adjacency matrix example, these matrices would look like this.

```
s = [ 7,    14,    13,    ...]
t = [ 6,    13,    12,    ...]
w = [-3.04, -2.03, -2.08, ...]
```

Here we've got the same edge from node `7` to node `6` with weight `-3.04`, and `14` to `13`, etc.

**Creating the digraph**

To feed this information to MATLAB's graph algorithms you need to create the proper structure using the function `digraph`, either

```
G = digraph(A);
```

or

```
G = digraph(s, t, w);
```

depending on which representation you chose.

**Use the shortestpath algorithm**

Once you've got `G`, it's just a matter of calling [shortestpath](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpath.html#inputarg_G). Since we're using the negatives of the original weights, this will actually be the longest path. You also need to give it the start and end nodes for the path. Using my numbering this would be `start_node = 7` and `end_node = 43`.

```
path = shortestpath(G, start_node, end_node);
```

This is the part where you might need to experiment a little bit. The `shortestpath` function actually has another parameter you can pass:

```
path = shortestpath(G, start_node, end_node, 'Method', <algorithm>);
```

That `<algorithm>` parameter allows you to select with shortest path algorithm will be used. If you don't specify the `'Method'`, from what I can see in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpath.html#inputarg_Method) it will default to `'Method', 'mixed'` because of the negative edge weights. This should work just fine and give you the longest path. Another option that looks interesting is `'Method', 'acyclic'` which might improve performance for larger graphs. If your grid is always going to be `7 x 7`, then it probably won't matter much and you can just take the default.

Comment: i do not understand how his problem can possibly be acyclic. can you explain it? also he says that he can do a maximum of 12 moves. I do not think that Dijkstra algorithm can be adapted in that way. Do you know a way?

Comment: @shamalaia The way I understood the problem, the only possible moves are to the left, or down. For each grid intersection there are (at most) two directed edges going out and (at most) two coming in. Once you have reached a given intersection, there is no way back up and to the right, so you can't ever reach that node again. As for the number of moves, I understood that to come from the Manhattan distance between the top-right and bottom-left corners. If I'm mistaken about the structure of the problem, then yes, we would have to re-think the solution.

Comment: dunno. I understood that we can move up/don and right/left: "allowed to do horizontal and vertical moves only" implies that loops are possible. I think that the limited number of moves is a bless.Brute force should be easily doable with only 12 moves.

Comment: Okay, let's try a constructive approach. Given a Manhattan distance of 12 between the top-right and bottom-left nodes, there is no path of length 12 that includes edges that go up or to the right. Any such edge will increase the Manhattan distance to the goal node.

Comment: @beaker you got it correct,actually by 12 moves we can only go to down or left,now can you explain it in a way i can solve too please?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili Sure, I'll try. What part do you need explanation on, the construction of the graph, or the implementation of the shortest path algorithm? For the second part, it would be good to know what version of MATLAB you have (2015b or later would be good) or if you have the Bioinformatics Toolbox.

Comment: Actually since i've never worked with graphs, i don't know how to do the first part,i have visited wikipedia but actually i got nothing...a point to mention is that i'm looking for the longest path possible,i'm using 2015b , i don't have a toolbox named bioinformatics...

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili Okay, this will be interesting, because I don't have 2015b and I've never used the new graph algorithm functions they added then. But I know graphs and the documentation seems straightforward enough, so we should be able to work it out. I'll edit my answer and you can try it out.

Comment: The descriptions were all clear,I really appreciate your helping and time devoting to my problem.thank you.

Comment: @beaker  
the method works only if i use the method as 'mixed' , and also i just assigned left and down moves i.e. A(4,3) and not A(3,4) or A(13,20) and not A(20,13) . but the answer isn't correct,the answer path length is 27.7 while matlab answer is 32.78