# Find best path maximizing score in 2D array

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, path-finding, optimal

I’m trying to implement a game where the allowed moves are left to right and top to down in a N x N 2D array with random positiv floats and a null trace (0 in diagonal). The moves are not restricted to 1 cell, each move is a shift of any number of squares to the right or down.

The starting position is the top row and first column and the ending arrival point can be anywhere. There are no blocker, we can follow any path as long as the move rules (to the right or to the bottom) are respected.

The score is computed only by tacking the ending point of each move, i.e if it goes from (0,0) to (0,4), only the value of element (0,4) contributes to the score, intermediate element value involved in the move are discarted from the score.
Score = sum(value of cell at move ending point)

I want to find the resulting value for the most profitable route.

I have tried the Dynamic Programming approach but it is not adapted to my problem.

```py
# A is the 2d array
# M is the matrix of optimal scores
# n is the size of the matrix
# path is the list of positions of the optimal path

def best_path(A, n):
  # Initialization of M with the values of A
  M = [[A[i][j] for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
  # Filling of M usine DP
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
      if i > 0 and j > 0:
        M[i][j] = max(M[i-1][j] + A[i][j], max(M[i][k] + A[i][j] for k in range(j)))
      elif i > 0 and j == 0:
        M[i][j] = M[i-1][j] + A[i][j]
      elif i == 0 and j > 0:
        M[i][j] = max(M[i][k] + A[i][j] for k in range(j))
  # The maximum score of the optimal path is M[n-1][n-1]
  score = M[n-1][n-1]
  # Initialization of the path with the end point
  path = [(n-1, n-1)]
  # Initialization of the indices i and j with the end point
  i = n-1
  j = n-1
  # Going back to the starting point by choosing the movement that maximizes the score
  while i > 0 or j > 0:
    if i > 0 and j > 0:
      if M[i][j] == M[i-1][j] + A[i][j]:
        # Move up
        i = i - 1
      else:
        # Move left until we find the k that maximizes the score
        k = max(range(j), key=lambda k: M[i][k] + A[i][j])
        j = k
    elif i > 0 and j == 0:
        # Move up 
      i = i - 1
    elif i == 0 and j > 0:
      # Move left until we find the k that maximizes the score
      k = max(range(j), key=lambda k: M[i][k] + A[i][j])
      j = k
    # Add the current position to the path
    path.append((i, j))
  # Reverse the path to have the right order
  path.reverse()
  # Return the score and the path
  return score, path
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Does distance have any effect on the score? You should also not use single letters for variable names.

Comment: Can you end at any point? Other than having 0s on the diagonal, does the matrix contain non-negative values or can it contain negative ones?

Comment: @boredProjects : no distance have no direct effect on the score but can affect the number of moves. Scores are computed simply as the sur of ending point of each move.

Comment: You have not defined the game properly here. How is the score computed? Path from where to where? What values are in each cell and how does that relate to the game? If it's a path, are there blockers? It sounds like a floyd warshall algorithm problem, but it's unclear.

Comment: @wLui155: yes i can end at any point and no the matrix contains only non negative value

Comment: @JPAlioto: thanks for the comment, I will edit my question

Comment: This struck me as more of a Dijkstra’s myself. Assuming your game has no negative numbers and there is a designated endpoint you should be able to just run a check across the grid to the right and down each time you move and just move to the largest value you find.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38400561/1377097